# Toyota Verso 1.6 VVTi 2006 Overheating 7 Not coming on

Tags: starting, ignition, lights, speedometer

How do I know if my head or black is damaged. Recently my Toyota Verso 1.6 VVTi 2006 Model overheated when I checked the water from the radiator I realised that there was white greasy thing on the radiator cap. That's when I realised that there's something wrong. My wife was driving the car always and I only picked it up later.

When I checked the dip stick it was fine, but not sure whether to take the block to engineering or recon my engine. Please help as I don't have the history of the car as we bought it second hand, not sure if the head was sent in to engineering to be skeemed or not.

What's the best solution to make sure I'm doing the right thing?

Thanks

Comment: Questions: You said, "... if my head or ***black*** is damaged." I'm not sure what you mean by black (or did you mean block?)? Also, you said you found a "white greasy thing" on the radiator cap. I'm assuming you mean there was a milky colored residue *under* the cap? How much does your wife drive the car (miles or km per week)? Are you seeing any globs of oil in the radiator fluid (it would usually float to the top after top off)?